# Conditional to check if a string is included in a list?

Tags: github-actions

How can I do `if github.event.action in ['foo', 'bar']` using GitHub Actions? I want to limit some actions from https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#release and the list of possible values is quite long.

Using `||` makes the entire construct huge, especially if you already need to combine it with other conditions.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contains? As noted in those docs you linked though, you can use `on: release: types: [...]` in this specific case.

Answer (score 22):

you can accomplish that with GitHub [functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#functions):

```yaml
contains(fromJson('["bar", "foo"]'), github.event.action)
```

sources:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson

example:

```yaml
...
jobs:
  some-job:
    # runs on pull_request if action is "opened" or "synchronize"
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && contains(fromJson('["opened", "synchronize"]'), github.event.action)
    ...
...
```

Comment: Why is `fromJson` needed here? The GitHub docs mention using it, but is there any reason it couldn't be `if: contains('["bar", "foo"]'), github.event.action)`?

Comment: @joshft91, `fromJson` is required to transform the string `'["bar", "foo"]'` into an array. without this `contains` will never find a match for `github.event.action` because it will try to match the string `'["bar", "foo"]'`.

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose there is no other way to represent an array without using `fromJson` since it would otherwise attempt to match a string like you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, clunky as hell, but works. Poor github...

Answer (score 3):

The closest one you can use is

`${{ contains(github.event.action, 'foo') || contains(github.event.action, 'bar') }}`

Documentation

`contains( search, item )`

Returns true if search contains item. If search is an array, this function returns true if the item is an element in the array. If search is a string, this function returns true if the item is a substring of search. This function is not case sensitive. Casts values to a string.

Example using an array
`contains(github.event.actions, 'bug')`

Example using a string
`contains('Hello world', 'llo')` returns true

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contains